# Probabilistic interpretation for Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, mathematical-physics

It is well known that if $X_t$ is a stochastic process that solves the SDE
$$dX_t = \mu(X_t,t)\,\mathrm{d}t + \sigma(X_t,t)\,\mathrm{d}W_t,$$
with $W_t$ a Wiener process, then the associated probability density $p(x,t)$ solves
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = -\nabla \cdot (\mu p) + \frac 12 \nabla \nabla : (Dp),$$
where $D_{ij} =\sum_{k} \sigma_{ik}\sigma_{jk}$ is symmetric, positive semi-definite. [(as summarized e.g. here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation)

Now, in [the same article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation), it is written that by interpreting the stochastic SDE in the **Stratonovich** sense rather than the **Ito** sense, one instead arrives at the corresponding equation
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = -\nabla \cdot (\mu p) + \frac 12 \sum_{i,k} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left( \sigma_{ik} \sum_{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left[\sigma_{kj} p\right]\right).$$
I'm wondering if there is yet a third way to interpret the SDE which would lead to a parabolic equation in divergence-form for the probability density? I.e. to 
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = -\nabla \cdot (\mu p) + \frac 12 \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left( D_{ij} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_j}\right).$$
Does anyone know if that's possible? Thank you.

Comment: I do not know if it leads to a divergence form, but there are other interpretation of the discretization rule for sde, ito taking the leftmost time point, Stratonovich the midpoint, finally the other more general approach is the so-called alpha-type interpretation (arxiv.org/abs/1203.6600). Have a look, it may be connected to your question !

Comment: @zebullon: Thanks! It now appears that the alpha-type interpretation with $\alpha = 1$, i.e. evaluation of the integrand at the rightmost point, might lead to a divergence-form [(see this)](http://journals.aps.org/pre/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevE.76.011123). At least from a very coarse reading of this paper... I will have to check in detail.

Comment: It seems that the $\alpha = 1$ interpretation only yields a divergence-form for the special case of a one-dimensional problem -- at least in general.